# Fatal error: Class 'medoo' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, slim, medoo, slim-2

I am using slim framework 2 with medoo via composer, i am making `singleton` for medoo but when i call the medoo class to configure my db info, so it gives me the `fatal error` like below

> Fatal error: Class 'medoo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\school\s.php
>   on line 5

below is my `s.php` file

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  $app = new\Slim\Slim();
    $app->container->singleton('test',function () use ($app) {
      return new medoo([
        'database_type' =>'mysql',
        'database_name' =>'mydb',
        'server'=> 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'option' => [
          PDO::ATTR_CASE=>PDO::CASE_NATURAL
        ]
      ]);
    });

    $app->get('/', function () use($app) {
      echo "<center><b><a href='#' target='_blank' >WELCOME TO TESTING PAGE</a></b></center>";
      $sth = $app->test->insert("t", ["id" =>1, "name" => "dsfdsf"]);
      var_dump($sth);
    });

  $app->run();
?>
```

If i check the `composer.json` file then i find slim and medoo both are there, i am not getting why this `fatal error` is coming please help me

Comment: You may see this official doc https://medoo.in/api/collaboration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

- you need to import the class
- your class name should be case-sensitive

That is:

```
<?php

use Medoo\Medoo;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->container->singleton('test',function () use ($app) {
    return new Medoo([
        // ...
    ]);
});
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php
- https://github.com/catfan/Medoo/tree/v1.4.5

Comment: then there will be no sense for using singleton,  if use namespace medoo every time

Comment: thanks , but i did it without use namespace medoo for singleton

Comment: What version of `catfan/medoo` are you using?

Comment: medoo version is 1.4 latest one

Comment: What do you mean by *did it without use namespace medoo for singleton*?

Comment: The namespace of a class name used for constructing an instance of a service has nothing to do with the concept of a *singleton* within the context of service containers. A singleton service just means that - regardless of how often you try to fetch a service from a container - the same instance will be returned (as opposed to a new one every time). See http://docs.slimframework.com/di/overview/#singleton-resources.

Comment: You don't need to `use Meedo\Meedo` every time, just where you're creating a new instance. This answer is answer is correct. Also I'm curious to know how did you manage to create a new Meedo instance without using the namespace this class is defined under?

Comment: @Nima Are you asking me or the original poster?

Comment: I'm asking the original poster. Sorry, I forgot to mentioned him.